# Fractional exponent equality

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Prove that if
$$\sqrt{x^2+(x^4y^2)^\frac 13}+\sqrt{y^2+(x^2y^4)^\frac 13}=a $$
Then
$$x^\frac 23+y^\frac 23=a^\frac 23$$

Comment: Just operate carefully. For instance: $x^2+(x^4y^2)^\frac{1}{3}=x^\frac{4}{3}(x^\frac{2}{3}+y^\frac{2}{3})$...